# Running Different Processes In Multiple Threads Without Overlapping In VB.NET 2

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, threadpool

I have a sub-procedure which I want to run a different process, depending on what is currently running. I thought the easiest way to do this was by using an ArrayList of each of the campaign details & adding an 'Inuse' field to check to see if the Inuse field is set to 0 or 1. The problem that I have is that when running the process it is all happening at once & the integer hasn't been changed before the next thread kicks in so my threads are running the same campaigns.

I tried to avoid the problem by adding a Thread.Sleep(100) delay inbetween starting threads but this led to exactly the same problem.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
    Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Campaigns As New ArrayList
    Private ProcessRunning As Boolean = False
    Friend StopProcess As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i = 0 To Campaigns.Count - 1
            Dim objNewThread As New Thread(AddressOf RunProcess)
            objNewThread.IsBackground = True
            objNewThread.Start()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateCells(ByVal CampID As Integer, ByVal Column As String, ByVal newText As String)
        Dim CellItemNum As Integer
        If Column = "Status" Then CellItemNum = 4
        DataGridView2.Rows(CampID).Cells.Item(CellItemNum).Value = newText
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            Campaigns.Add({Campaigns.Count(), "Campaign " & i, "Keywords " & i, "Link " & i, 5, True, 0, 0})
        Next
        DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
        For Each Campaign In Campaigns
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New String() {Campaign(1), Campaign(2), Campaign(3), Campaign(6), ""})
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RunProcess()
        ' Set Variables
        Dim CampID As Integer
        Dim CampName As String
        Dim Keywords As String
        Dim Link As String
        Dim CheckEvery As Integer
        Dim OkToUse As Boolean
        Dim Sent As Integer
        ' Find A Free Campaign
        For i As Integer = 0 To Campaigns.Count - 1
            ' Check If Inuse
            If Campaigns(i)(7) = 1 Then Continue For Else Campaigns(i)(7) = 1 ' This Line Sets Campaign To Inuse
            ' Most of the time only campaign(0) and campaign(1) are selected & multiple threads are running them instead of choosing unique campaigns
            ' Set Campaign Details
            CampID = Campaigns(i)(0)
            CampName = Campaigns(i)(1)
            Keywords = Campaigns(i)(2)
            Link = Campaigns(i)(3)
            CheckEvery = Campaigns(i)(4)
            OkToUse = Campaigns(i)(5)
            Sent = Campaigns(i)(6)
            ' Start Process
            UpdateCells(CampID, "Status", "Looking Up New Links (" & CampID & ")")
            Exit For
        Next
        While StopProcess = False
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            UpdateCells(CampID, "Status", "Running Process (" & CampID & ")")
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            For i = 0 To CheckEvery
                UpdateCells(CampID, "Status", "Re-Checking In " & (CheckEvery - i) & " Seconds")
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Next
        End While
        ' Closing Processes
        Campaigns(CampID)(7) = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The word "Process" has a specific meaning, and this isn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SyncLock to force your threads to wait.

class level so all threads access same lock

```
private myLock as new Object
```

Then use syncLock when you start your process and end it when you are done.

```
SyncLock myLock
  'process code here
End SyncLock
```

More [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y0) info on the subject

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into QueueUserWorkItem():

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 0 To Campaigns.Count - 1
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf RunProcess), Campaigns[i])
    Next
End Sub
```

Then change the RunProcess() method to include the Campaign object sent in by the work item:

```
Private Sub RunProcess(ByVal o As System.Object)
    ' Process the Campaign
    Dim campaign As Campaign = Ctype(o, Campaign)
End Sub
```

There will be no need for inuse, plus threads will be managed by the managed ThreadPool!

Comment: I edited your declaring the campaign in run process to the proper vb syntax.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you! Don't mind at all. I did a VB.Net project back in 2003; forgot much since then.

Comment: If the threadpool has multiple worker threads wouldn't this still have the same potential issue?

Comment: This wouldn't have the same issue as you are calling a specific campaign with Campaigns[i] for each campaign. Also a valid answer but I ended up going with the SyncLock command :)

Comment: Also, I may look into ThreadPool in the future, for the time being I will give it a miss as my needs were met in just 3 lines of code being added with SyncLock, for my next app I'll give this a shot though.